# Google DriveService C# leaking HttpConnection objects

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I have an application that utilizes Google's Drive service using the C# SDK.  I am using Service Account credentials, with impersonation to specify the user I am acting on behalf of.

The issue I'm having is that I need to create a new DriveService for each impersonated user, and each of those DriveService isntances creates 2 HttpConnection objects that are NOT cleaned up when I Dispose() the DriveService.  I have repro'd this in a unit test.  I create the DriveService in this method:

```
public DriveService GetDriveService(string email)
    {
        var serviceAccountEmail = "service account email";
        var privateKey = "private key";

        var serviceAcctCreds =  new ServiceAccountCredential(new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
        {
            User = email,
            Scopes = "scopes" }), 
        }.FromPrivateKey(privateKey));

        var driveService = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
        { 
            HttpClientInitializer = serviceAcctCreds,
            ApplicationName = "app name",
        });

        return driveService;
    }
```

Then use it as so:

```
public async Task DoTheGDriveMemoryTest()
        {
            var userEmails = new List<string>
            {
                 "email1@example.com", "email2@example.com"
            };
            var i = 1;
            while (true)
            {
                foreach (var email in userEmails)
                {
                    //recommend using Fiddler Autoresponders here
                    using (var service = GetDriveService(email))
                    {
                        var request = service.Changes.List("delta id");                        
                        try
                        {
                            var result = await request.ExecuteAsync();
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            //do nothing
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

This results in an ever-increasing number of HttpConnection objects held in memory, that are not cleaned up with Garbage Collection.

Comment: I'm getting some comments related to the underlying usage of HttpClient, which are valid.  The issue here is that when authenticating with a Service Account, we must provide the "User" property of the ServiceAccountCredentials to specify which user we are impersonating on a specific call.  This precludes us from re-using the DriveService, which is where the HttpClient is contained.  So, maybe a more appropriate question is "How can I re-use the DriveService for impersonated Users".

Answer (score 0):

If DriveService is using HttpClient under the covers, you may be running into dispose not working on a shared object, or connections being held until a timeout.

> But HttpClient is different. Although it implements the IDisposable interface it is actually a shared object.

See https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/

Comment: Related article: https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/introduction-to-httpclientfactory-aspnetcore

Comment: We are re-using the HttpClient in other areas of the application, but this one is out of our control.  When impersonating users, we are forced to create a new HttpClientInitializer for each user, which means if we have 10k users, we have 10k HttpClientInitializer and 10k DriveService instances, all of which have their own HttpClient.

Answer (score 0):

As Mike M has stated, this is a known problem with `HttpClient` in that its `Dispose()` method doesn't really dispose of the instance.

Unfortunately because the way the `Google.Apis.Auth` library ties together the `HttpClient` and the credentials, I can't see a nice workaround for this.

Here is a very hacky workaround, that allows you to share one HttpClient between all the RPCs.
Define a custom `IHttpClientFactory`:

```
class SharedHttpClientFactory : IHttpClientFactory
{
    public SharedHttpClientFactory()
    {
        _handler = new ConfigurableMessageHandler(new HttpClientHandler());
        _client = new ConfigurableHttpClient(_handler);
    }

    private readonly ConfigurableMessageHandler _handler;
    private readonly ConfigurableHttpClient _client;
    private Action _clearHandlers = null;

    public ConfigurableHttpClient CreateHttpClient(CreateHttpClientArgs args)
    {
        _clearHandlers?.Invoke();
        var executeInterceptors = args.Initializers.OfType<IHttpExecuteInterceptor>().ToList();
        var unsuccessfulResponseHandlers = args.Initializers.OfType<IHttpUnsuccessfulResponseHandler>().ToList();
        _clearHandlers = () =>
        {
            foreach (var executeInterceptor in executeInterceptors)
            {
                _handler.RemoveExecuteInterceptor(executeInterceptor);
            }
            foreach (var unsuccssfulResponseHandler in unsuccessfulResponseHandlers)
            {
                _handler.RemoveUnsuccessfulResponseHandler(unsuccssfulResponseHandler);
            }
        };
        foreach (var executeInterceptor in executeInterceptors)
        {
            _handler.AddExecuteInterceptor(executeInterceptor);
        }
        foreach (var unsuccssfulResponseHandler in unsuccessfulResponseHandlers)
        {
            _handler.AddUnsuccessfulResponseHandler(unsuccssfulResponseHandler);
        }
        _handler.ApplicationName = args.ApplicationName;
        return _client;
    }
}
```

Create a single instance of this factory:

```
var factory = new SharedHttpClientFactory();
```

Then create every `DriveService` using this factory:

```
var client = new StorageService(new Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService.Initializer
{
    HttpClientFactory = factory,
    HttpClientInitializer = serviceAcctCreds
});
```

Caveats abound:

- Do not dispose of the `DriveService` as this will dispose of the underlying shared `HttpClient`.
- All the `DriveService` instances share the same credentials; these credentials are changed each time a new `DriveService` is instantiated. This means that all previous instances *also* have their credentials updated.
- The credential passed into the initializer `HttpClientInitializer` property *must* be a `ServiceCredential` instance (as it is in your code). This won't work if it's a `GoogleCredential` instance.
- This whole thing isn't really advised, is definitely a nasty hack, but I can't see a better/simpler workaround.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  The 2nd caveat is likely the primary reason this won't work:  I'm creating DriveService instances on different threads for different users, so need to be able to change credential.  It appears I'm going to just have to write my own code to hit the REST API's.